# How to integrate this nasty integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you go about integrating this? For context purposes, $s$ is a constant and $n$ is just the variable we need to integrate for. If needed, a number can be substituted for $s$, but I would like it without preferably.

$$\int\frac{s\sqrt{3}\sqrt{s^2-2ns\sqrt{7}+4n^2}}{2s^2-4ns\sqrt{7}+8n^2}dn$$

Comment: Are you sure about the coefficients ? Numerator and denominator simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{s\sqrt{3}\sqrt{s^2-2ns\sqrt{7}+4n^2}}{2s^2-4ns\sqrt{7}+8n^2}=\frac{s\sqrt{3}}2\frac{\sqrt{s^2-2ns\sqrt{7}+4n^2}}{s^2-2ns\sqrt{7}+4n^2}=\frac{s\sqrt{3}}2 \frac 1{\sqrt{s^2-2ns\sqrt{7}+4n^2}}$$
So, you need to compute
$$I=\int \frac {dn}{\sqrt{an ^2+bn+c}}$$ Complete the square first  to arrive to a very simple integral.

Comment: How would I complete the square and solve that final integral if you don't mind? Also how did you get the coefficients of a, b, and c?

Comment: @Anish Shah. I just made the problem more general.